# Two Data sent during internet slow down in my HTTP Request?

Tags: android

I have an applications that send data using HTTP post request to a server, is it possible if your internet connection slows down during the process to send the data twice?

I mean you only send the data once but due to internet connection is fluctuating it send your data twice. something like refresh.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your code, might be you have called execute twice. Are you using an Async Task? You can as well check the speed of your connection using a simple function.

Comment: Actually my application is working fine, and i sure that i only sent the request once. and not all the data i sent were being duplicate, i only experience one incident only. so i'm just wondering if the connection can affect the sending of data.

Answer (score 2):

No, android will not resend your data. If there's there's connection error, then there's connection error returned from httpclient. Unless you use any http helper that do resending, then you must be sending data twice yourself.

Comment: Hi, i'm facing similar issue from my android client making an http request to `MySql` via php web service, when internet connection is slow an empty row get's inserted into the Table. On wifi everything works fine. It seems like data is getting Lost for slow connection.

Comment: this makes no sense really because network speed does not matter in terms of reliability. As long as it not timeouted then it does not matter if its' 1Tb/s or 500 bytes per second link. You must have bugs elsewhere

Comment: `As long as it not timeouted` can you please this i thing this could be a culprit. And do you mean the timeout could become the cause of empty insertion.

Comment: I mean that speed of connection is not really important. Internet protocols ensures at various levels that data is correctly transmitted. So you your HTTP request did not return any errors, then it means data has been successfully sent to the other end. If it failed, then you got error returned and you know you need to retry.

Comment: I'm using a free hosting! And one more question is there any chance that POST REQUEST can miss data? and will imposing time out at the client or server side can help?

Comment: Theoretically yest, but this is very unlikely and you should look for bugs elsewhere almost for sure.

Comment: `Theoretically yes` this yes is for POST missing data? or timeout fix?

Comment: And believe me if there is a bug it should happens for wifi too ( i mean good internet speed). And i doubt that may be the post data is getting miss or may be taking too much time while the connection to the MySQL gets open and query getting executed any way!